# Azure function context log not logging properly, not synchronous

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-functions, serverless

I expect the following to log in order from top to bottom but results show that they're not in order

```
// Azure function handler
export const browseIssues = context => {
  context.log.info({ a: 'first object', b: { q: 'test 1' } });
  context.log.info({ a: 'second object', b: { q: 'test 2' } });
  context.log.info({ a: 'third object', b: { q: 'test 3' } });

  context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a: 'first string', b: { q: 'test 1' } }));
  context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a: 'second string', b: { q: 'test 2' } }));
  context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a: 'third string', b: { q: 'test 3' } }));

  context.log.info('first simple string');
  context.log.info('second simple string');
  context.log.info('third simple string');
}
```

Results:
[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to remedy this? Issue seems to be confined in azure context's log as console.log logs synchronously.

Node version: v18.12.1

No middleware used in this example.

EDIT:
extra info - here's a barebone repo where it's reproducible
https://github.com/keidyz/azure-function-logging-issue

Comment: I cant even get context.log to log to terminal. Can you share your settings?

Comment: @qkhanhpro updated the question to have the configs. It's pretty bare bones and I just use `func start` directly to start it up

Comment: @kdyz, I can see the same issue - https://i.imgur.com/ymEnKEw.png - Context Logging is not in sequential order.

Comment: @HariKrishna I wonder if it's an issue with azure function's context.log itself. Will be posting this on Microsoft's site directly.

Comment: I have raised the issue with all the information in Azure Functions Host Issues official Forum - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9146

Answer (score 0):

From my practical, I observed the same issue which is `Context Logging` not doing in Sequential Order.

[image]

```js
module.exports = async  function (context) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
  

context.log.info({ a:  'first object', b: { q:  'test 1' } });
context.log.info({ a:  'second object', b: { q:  'test 2' } });
context.log.info({ a:  'third object', b: { q:  'test 3' } });
context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a:  'first string', b: { q:  'test 1' } }));
context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a:  'second string', b: { q:  'test 2' } }));
context.log.info(JSON.stringify({ a:  'third string', b: { q:  'test 3' } }));

context.log.info('first simple string');
context.log.info('second simple string');
context.log.info('third simple string');
const  responseMessage = "Hello Krishna, This Http Triggered Function executed successfully."


context.res = {
body:  responseMessage
};
}
```

I have raised the issue with all the code snippets of Azure Functions Node JS to get the above result in the Azure Functions Host Issues Official Forum - #[9146](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9146) and will follow-up accordingly.